# Access contents of buffers from outside

Tags: buffers, emacsclient

I want to access contents of emacs buffers from outside like in [acme editor](https://9p.io/sys/doc/acme/acme.html).

> Acme is in part a file server that exports device-like files that may be manipulated to access and control the contents of its windows.

And no I don't want plugin that makes emac behave like acme etc. I just want to be able to access and control the contents of buffers.

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Try using the daemon and emacsclient.

Comment: @wasamasa The daemon is not required for the objectives of the question even if it is related to the topic.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer, as the current implementation is experimental, but [here](https://github.com/vkazanov/elfuse) is a project, that among its goals, aims to expose emacs buffers as files, in a sort-of-plan9 way, via FUSE.

Comment: Useful question.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to read and write the contents of a buffer with the combination of an [emacs server](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html) and an `emacsclient`. (If you want you can run the server as `daemon`.)

Demo:

- Start emacs.
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `server-start` <kbd>RET</kbd> starts the server. Before you start the server you can set the name through the option `server-name`.
- Create a buffer with known name, e.g. by <kbd>C-x b</kbd> `mybuf` <kbd>RET</kbd> (this could also be done with `emacsclient`)
- Write some text in the buffer, e.g., `some text`
- As a small example how to read buffer contents open a `xterm` and run there:

  ```
  emacsclient --server-file server --eval "(with-current-buffer \"mybuf\" (prin1 (buffer-string)))"
  ```
- As a small example how to insert stuff into the buffer run in the same `xterm`:

  ```
  emacsclient --server-file server --eval "(with-current-buffer \"mybuf\" (insert \"\\nHello from the outside world.\"))"
  ```

## Notes:

- Depending on your system and your emacs configuration it may be that you need to substitute `--server-file` by `--socket-name` in the call of `emacsclient`.
- If you use the standard server name `server` you don't need the option `--server-file server` (or `--socket-name server`).